# Was there a Role of Technology in Macroeconomic Models before Solow?

Tags: economic-growth, solow, technological-progress

Was the role of *technological progress* formalised by Solow (1956) for the first time? or at least he provided the initial formal insight into the role of technological progress in economic growth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solow model was indeed the first model to account for technological progress.

While models like the the  [Harrod-Domar model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrod%E2%80%93Domar_model) and the Neo-Marxian  [Feldman–Mahalanobis model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldman%E2%80%93Mahalanobis_model) conciser investment and saving as contributors to economic growth, they don't consider any measure of technology like total factor productivity to contribute to economic growth, like the [Solow Residual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solow_residual).